# Inner Join to select max date for each id in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with an id as per below with about 200k records

| bookid |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

and another containing info relating to dates for each date as per below that holds well over 300k records

| bookid | bookdate |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2020 |
| 1 | 1/1/2022 |
| 2 | 1/1/2023 |
| 2 | 1/1/2027 |
| 474000 | 1/1/2023 |
| 474000 | 1/1/2027 |

I am looking to perform a join to return only the MAX(bookdate for each id).

But I cant use 'where policy IN()' due to the volumes involved.
Any help appreciated, thanks. :)

Comment: *But I cant use 'where policy IN()'* can you provide more details about this `policy` field never referenced before? Also can you share your coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: I meant where bookid IN()

Comment: I dont have an attempt as I cant figure it out without using IN() clause

Answer (score 2):

You can get the maximum value of *bookdate* for each registered *bookid*, then using a left join between *Table1* and the previously generated table to avoid losing bookid that may not have a bookdate at all:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT bookid,
           MAX(bookdate) AS max_bookdate
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY bookid
)
SELECT Table1.bookid,
       cte.max_bookdate
FROM      Table1
LEFT JOIN cte
       ON Table1.bookid = cte.bookid
```

If you need to do these values multiple times, consider storing the output of this query inside a table:

```
CREATE TABLE book_max_dates AS
SELECT Table1.bookid,
       cte.max_bookdate
FROM      Table1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT bookid,
                  MAX(bookdate) AS max_bookdate
           FROM Table2
           GROUP BY bookid                     ) cte
       ON Table1.bookid = cte.bookid
```

Note: this code assumes that every bookid in *Table2* exists in *Table1*, contrarily to the provided sample values for the two tables.